# Controller Namig. TagSelectController or TagSelectionController

Tags: swift, class, naming-conventions, naming

In my Xcode project, i have a controller which to select a tag from a list of tags.

I'm facing a problem how to name this controller.
I came up with the following.

- TagSelectController
- TagSelectionController

Which one should I choose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general for a view controller, you would typically use the suffix `ViewController`. Also, since "Tag Selection" is more grammatically correct than "Tag Select", it should be the name. So naming your viewController `TagSelectionViewController` would be the way to go.

If you're curious about looking further into Apple's suggested naming conventions, check out [their obj-c documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CodingGuidelines/CodingGuidelines.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000146-SW1) or [swift.org's suggestions](https://swift.org/documentation/api-design-guidelines/#naming).

Comment: So it was more about English grammar.  English is not my native tongue.  Also thank you for the nice reference links.